# What things do you consider when choosing a fixed base operator (FBO)?

Tags: fbo

I'm working on some marketing for a regional FBO and while I'm an aviation aficionado, I'm neither a pilot or deeply involved in the aviation industry.

I'd love your input on how you research and choose an FBO while doing your flight planning…

- As a pilot what are your primary considerations when choosing an FBO? Fuel cost, amenities, local knowledge, other things entirely?
- What things do you look at as distinguishing factors between competitors?
- Are there certain things that you consider mandatory from an FBO?
- What information do you want to "know before you go"?
- What online resources do you personally use when doing your flight planning and/or researching FBO's?
- Have you had an extremely positive (or terrible) experience with an FBO, so that I can research them?

I'll also note that this particular FBO is located in a fairly rural, yet growing region of the Western United States.

Look forward to your input and responses!

Comment: This seems mostly based on opinion, so it's not a good fit for the format here. If someone can address these topics well it may make a good post for [the blog](http://aviation.blogoverflow.com/). If you can edit it to make it more based on facts, maybe surveys or sales data, it would be a better fit here.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it's a difficult one to answer here. You're asking for multiple opinions, but the purpose of this site is to find the best possible answer to reasonably factual questions. That's not to say that opinions aren't valuable, it's just that StackExchange isn't really about them. You might want to drop into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) and see what people think, or perhaps you can make your question more focused and objective (I know that may not be useful in this case).

Answer (score 5):

I'll throw in my 2 cents here but I am by no means super experienced in this realm.

1. Amenities is not a huge deal for me. Generally I fly to go somewhere, while a nice interior is always a bonus, I'm fine as long as there is a bathroom and a receptionist to pay. Generally I'm at the airport to tie up and then leave and go about my business. Some place to sit to wait for weather to improve is nice but I by no means care if the couch is leather or 1970's velour as long as I can sit on it for a while.
2. I flight plan with ForeFlight.com so I won't comment on what you should have but in today's day and age I would consider a WiFi connection in the FBO a must have since lots of people use tablet based planning now.
3. Fuel cost is always a consideration and you should try and remain competitive to your local areas as much as possible.
4. The key for me is a well laid out and clear website that lists prices for what ever you offer and other important information. Maybe an airport map with the location of the FBO clearly marked. A phone number to call for questions is also important.
5. A solid relationship with a local taxi service is a bonus and a courtesy or rental car would be even better, but I understand how this could be a runaway cost on some level.
6. Local knowledge is good if there are specific things that may be odd about the airspace and major airport issues that may arise.

Comment: +1 for the WiFi... and not just any lame wifi:  An FBO that has big bandwidth and strong enough signal that I can download updated maps from the Ramp area is a really nice thing.